# libgdx - Cannot get sprite to appear on body

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

So I have tried several different ways to put the sprite on to my coin bodies but to no avail. I initially just tried putting a texture on it, but that didn't work. Then I tried using the texture packer and atlas to see if that would help. Here is my code:

```
public class Coin extends Item {

public Coin(PlayScreen screen, float x, float y) {
    super(screen, x, y);
    setRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("Coin"), 0, 0, 15, 16);
}

@Override
public void defineItem() {
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(getX(), getY());
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;       
    body = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(10/Racing.PPM);

    fdef.shape = shape;


    Filter filter = new Filter();
    filter.categoryBits = Racing.COIN_BIT;
    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fdef);
    fixture.setFilterData(filter);
    fixture.setUserData(this);

}   

public void update(float dt){
    super.update(dt);
    setPosition(body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
}
}
```

And it extends this class:

```
public abstract class Item extends Sprite{
 protected PlayScreen screen;
    protected World world;
    protected Vector2 velocity;
    protected boolean toDestroy;
    protected boolean destroyed;
    protected Body body;

    public Item(PlayScreen screen, float x, float y){
        this.screen = screen;
        this.world = screen.getWorld();
        toDestroy = false;
        destroyed = false;

        setPosition(x, y);
        setBounds(getX(), getY(), 16 / Racing.PPM, 16 / Racing.PPM);
        defineItem();
    }

    public abstract void defineItem();
    public abstract void collect(Kart kart);

    public void update(float dt){
        if(toDestroy && !destroyed){
            world.destroyBody(body);
            destroyed = true;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Batch batch){
        if(!destroyed){
            super.draw(batch);
        }
    }

    public void destroy(){
        toDestroy = true;
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!